# "Real time" changeable class design

Tags: c#, winforms

My application is used for centrifugal pump impeller design. User is allowed to change some of the properties (flow speed, dimensions, etc.) in real time through winform gui and he should be provided real time with most of the results.

There is 13 user changeable parameters and around 70 calculated ones.

Most of calculation are quite complex mathematically and one of parameter needs iteration (no more then 10 iterations).

My solutions for class which contains and calculates all parameters so far were:

1. Class using properties describing user changeable parameters and methods calculating resulting parameters.
2. Class which is immutable and calculates everything while created.
3. Lazy solution using Lazy class from .NET 4.0

I have asked [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13475/multiple-properties-updated-by-event-vs-few-properties-and-methods) question on CR that is from where i have got Lazy solution.

So my question is which method will be most suitable for "real time" solution? Are there any other better solutions?

Comment: Is performance an issue?  That is, recalculating those 70 parameters individually whenever they're needed a bottleneck?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair So far for the 1st solution it is working quite good but some of the methods are called more then 100 times just after user  changes one parameter.

Comment: Perhaps option #2 is the best then.  Let the user input the new driving parameters they want, create a new object with those parameters and have it pre-calculate the 70 others once and feed that object into the system.  At least that way you don't get into a situation where you calculate values while simultaneously the user is updating other values.  EDIT: Maybe try splitting the object into 2.  First class serves as input parameters _only_, which has a `Calculate` method which returns the second, immutable class which contains all the input parameters _and_ the 70 driven values.

Comment: That second class is what drives the rest of your system.  The rest of the system doesn't care _how_ you got to those values, so that frees your GUI to do whatever lazy/non-lazy work it wants to do and feeds a simple immutable object to the business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with solution 1, I suspect each pump has the same properties, just different values for the properties.

```
public class Pump
{
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
    public void GetCFM() { return Speed * Size; }
}
```

Any call to `GetCFM` would always return the most up-to-date calculation.

If you don't want to manually call `GetCFM`, you could implement the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) instead.  Using the *Observer Pattern* you would trigger an handler that gets notified any time any of the properties change.

Also, I suspect your understanding of [real time computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) is different than what's explained in the article.

Comment: It was my first approach but when i have noticed that methods where unnecessarily called multiple times for example: public void GetABC() { return GetCFM() * GetDEF(); } also textBox.Text = GetABC().ToString() I've started to look for something which will save the value until next recalculation. I am still using this solution but it just doesn't seem right :).

Comment: You can have a private/protected method that you call to get the calculation, and when you change a property (within the properties `set` method) you call this method which saves the value internally, and then is exposed with a different property.  I would recommend that you do *not* do this, however, as it will lead to really hard to understand code.  Computers are very fast at calculating numbers and unless you actually observe a bottleneck, you may just be writing more complex (and difficult to maintain) code unnescessarily.

Comment: Real time meant that user don't need to press submit button or something similar and is provided with recalculated values after each change.

Comment: @Archibald that can be achieved simply by listening to the various `OnChange` events of the GUI controls, recalculating, and repopulating the values.

Comment: That is what is called a *reactive user interface*, which so long as the calculation can be done in a reasonable amount of time, then I don't see any need to make your solution more complicated.  Anything under 100ms would feel instant to most people.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair That is actually what i'm doing. Maybe "real time" wasn't the best choice of words but that is why i've used "".

Comment: @Archibald So is the GUI not performing well enough with what you have now?  Is it slowing down whenever it recalculates data?  Or are you asking for a better way to manage/organize your classes for maintainability/readability?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair GUI is performing well enough for 1st solution even with some charts, tables and 3d preview of impeller model. It just seems not good enough for me when I have noticed that methods are repeated so many times.

Comment: @Archibald My recommendation is if it's creating correct calculations, fast enough, and it's easy to maintain, then I would leave it.

Comment: Could be premature optimization then.  If you want to avoid recalculating the values each time, you have a few options.  Might be hard to say depending on the particulars of your design and how you use them though.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Since i'm kind of virgin programmer it might be premature optimization :). What do U think about lazy solution? Pls write at least short answer so i could +1 you.